# Dynamically change JButton Properties at runtime

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jbutton

What is the correct way to change a JButtons Property at runtime?

This code snippet doesent work.

```
private HashMap<Integer, JButton> fieldMap;

private void updateButton(int coordinate){
JButton fieldBtn = FieldMap.get(coordinate);
fieldBtn.setOpaque(true);
fieldBtn.setBackground(Color.red);
fieldBtn.setText(String.valueOf(text));
fieldBtn.updateUI();
Board.updateUI();
}
```

Comment: Never call `updateUI`, it doesn't do what you think it does and it's a very expensive call.  `setText` and `setBackground` are bound properties, this means that they will automatically trigger updates to the UI which should cause the UI to update.  This suggests that the problem is elsewhere within the code. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to update the button at runtime.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class UpdateButton{
    private JFrame frame;
    private DemoPanel demoPanel;
    JComboBox styleList;
    private JButton button;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                UpdateButton updateButton = new UpdateButton();
                updateButton.createUI();
                updateButton.displayUI();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void createUI(){
        frame = new JFrame("Update Button");
        ActionPanel actionPanel = new ActionPanel();
        demoPanel = new DemoPanel();
        frame.add(actionPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(demoPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    public void displayUI(){
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void doUpdate(String styleName){
        if(styleName.equals("Style1")){
            button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            button.setText("Style1 Button");
        }else if(styleName.equals("Style2")){
            button.setBackground(Color.green);
            button.setText("Style2 Button");
        }else if(styleName.equals("Style3")){
            button.setBackground(Color.pink);
            button.setText("Style3 Button");
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class ActionPanel extends JPanel{
        public ActionPanel(){
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(getBorder(), "ActionPanel", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Default",Font.PLAIN,10), Color.gray));
            String[] style= { "Style1", "Style2", "Style3"};
            styleList = new JComboBox(style);
            styleList.addItemListener(new styleListener());
            add(styleList);
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class DemoPanel extends JPanel{
        public DemoPanel(){
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(getBorder(), "DemoPanel", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Default",Font.PLAIN,10), Color.gray));
            button = new JButton("Ordinary Button");
            add(button);
        }
    }
    
    class styleListener implements ItemListener{
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                String styleName = (String)e.getItem();
                doUpdate(styleName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the effect:

[image]